# Is there a way to "overload" or reimplement __stack_chk_fail?

Tags: c, gcc, buffer-overflow

I want to enable stack protection feature in gcc for a system i am building that run on x86 linux.

I want that if it detects stack smashing it would call a function of my own that will handle the case or it will call my own implementation of the function `__stack_chk_fail` , is there a way to do it?

So far i tried to undef `__stack_chk_fail` and `__stack_chk_guard` and then defining them myself but it didn't work and resulted in segmentation fault when trying exploiting buffer overflow.
Here is an example of what i did:

```
    #undef __stack_chk_guard
    #undef __stack_chk_fail
    uintptr_t __stack_chk_guard = 0xdeadbeef;

    void __stack_chk_fail(void)
    {
        printf("Stack smashing detected");
    }

   void foo(void)
   {
    char buffer[2];
    strcpy(buffer, "hello, I am smashing your stack!");
   }
```

I also tried using `LD_PRELOAD` but that resulted in segmentation fault when smashing the stack but it also resulted in segmentation fault.

Comment: C does not support overloading, it is a different language than C++. Don't spam tags.

Comment: @Olaf i know c doesn't support method overloading but i don't have better name for what i am trying to do

Comment: So, as you decided you use C, I still wonder why you used the C++ tag, too. One way or the other, my comment applies. Re your question: what do you mean with "undef ..." you cannot "undef" a variable or function. It's not a macro. Regarding the segfault: You invoke undefined behaviour and your code behave undefined. I'd say everything worked as expected, mission accomplished, no problem.

Comment: @Olaf okay it might be the case that it is undefined behavior but my question still stands,is there a way to have my own handling when stack smashing occur?

Comment: `__stack_chk_fail` and `__stack_chk_guard` are GCC / glibc implementation details.  As far as I can determine, they are not part of any user-facing interface or language extension.  You are not meant to mess with them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger i know that they are part of glibc,and i agree that i shouldn't touch the implementation but it is quite reasonable to be able to do my own handling when stack smashing occur,as far as i know when i turn on the stack protector flag it explicitly calls `__stack_chk_fail` and that's why i need to define my implementation with that name

Comment: @omer12433, although it is not unreasonable to want to insert your own logic, my point is that *GCC does not offer you that alternative*.  You may nevertheless be able to hack something together, but you will be working against GCC and glibc to accomplish that, not with them.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok i understand it i asked here because i wan't to avoid a "hacky" way to do it,because of obvious reason(such as maintenance and depending on specific compiler or glibc version)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research i found out i can use the linker flag `--wrap` to wrap `__stack_chk_fail` and insert my own hanlding just as i wanted.

The flag change each call of `__stack_chk_fail` to `__wrap___stack_chk_fail` and each call to `__real___stack_chk_fail` to `__stack_chk_fail`

I can even skip calling the real `__stack_chk_fail` if i wanted to

below is an example code in a file named `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void __real___stack_chk_fail(void);

void __wrap___stack_chk_fail(void)
{
    printf("our test");
    __real___stack_chk_fail();
}
void func()
{
    char buffer[2];
    strcpy(buffer, "smashhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
}
int main(void)
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it execute:

```
gcc -fstack-protector-strong -c test.c
gcc -Wl,--wrap=__stack_chk_fail test.o
```

The ouput would be "our test" and then the regular behavior of  `__stack_chk_fail`

UPDATE:

Another way to do it is to exclude libssp from the linkage process with the flag `--exclude-libs,libssp` and implement `__stack_chk_fail` and `guard_setup`(the function that initiate `__stack_chk_guard` value) on your own

Comment: I tried your example with gcc and clang, `__wrap___stack_chk_fail`  was never called.  I tried the second method with clang++ (since wrapping doesn't seem to work in C++) and it still used the system  `__stack_chk_fail`.  I feel like I'm missing something. :(

Comment: Update: What I wrote above was my experience, but I did manage to get it working: Using C++, prefixing the definition of `__stack_chk_fail` with `extern "C"` (I had forgotten about that, I'm not a C programmer :) ) _e.g._ `extern "C" auto __stack_chk_fail(void) -> void;` .  I didn't even need to exclude `libs,libssp`